# Style not applying on pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am making a new application with material design.I have app compact library to support pre lollipop devices.I have displayed a toolbar(action bar) in blue color.The code works fine in lollipop devices but when i run this app in pre lollipop devices the toolbar color doesnt change.

Style.Xml

```
<resources>


    <style name="HsJobTheme" parent="CustomTheme">


    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HsJobsToolBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fffffa12</item>

    </style>


</resources>
```

Style.Xml(V21)

```
<resources>

    <style name="HsJobTheme" parent="CustomTheme">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/HsJobsToolBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your **Activity** should look like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/HsJobsToolBar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in any layout that implements the toolbar something like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am using actionbar activity only but still it doesnt change in pre lollypop devices

Comment: Do you also have the attribute `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"` in the `AndroidManifest` ?

Comment: respectively `android:theme="@style/HsJobTheme"`

Comment: How do you include the toolbar in your layout?

Comment: <include layout=toolbar.xml>

Comment: Seems to be strange. I've tested my code fragment on an emulator with API level 19 and it works.. Have you adapted your code according to my proposal ? Can you edit your question and add the `Activity` and the layout?